# Showing that conditional entropies $H(X \mid Y)$ and $H(Y \mid X)$ are equal for delta distributions

Tags: entropy, information-theory

I need some help with the following problem.

What does it mean for the joint probability distribution of two random variables $x$   and $y$,  $p(x,y)$ , to be equal to $\delta (x,y)$ (Kronecker delta)?

And in that case, how do I show that the conditional entropies $H(X|Y)$ and $H(Y|X)$ are equal?

Here $ H( X| Y) = - \sum \sum p(x,y) \log p (x|y) $

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem or textbook question. If so, please tag as [tag:self-study]. What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Hi. There was a mistake in the question. The joint probability distribution would be P(x) Delta(x,y). I could do it after the correction.

Comment: There's another question that I am having some doubts about. Can I edit this one with the new question?

Comment: No, you should post it as a new question. If it’s related to this one, you can include a link to this one.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Okay, sure. Thanks.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I have posted a question in Mathematics SE. Please take a look, if possible. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4145502/766787